# Объединить два объекта в JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

Как можно объединить два объекта используя библиотеку THREE.js, чтобы двигать можно было по созданной карте? Чтобы не делать кучу клонируемых объектов.

```
var geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry(0.75, 0.05, 0.15, 32,);// обручи
        var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('https://img4.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/original/7/a8/tekstura-fon-polosy-tsvet-poverkhnost.jpg')
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture, transparent: false, opacity: 1.5}); //color: 0x7d0bc1
        `var torus2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);`
       ` torus2.rotation.z = Math.PI / 2;`
      `  torus2.position.set(5, -3.71, 1.3);`
        var torus3 = torus2.clone();
        torus3.position.set(5.1, -3.6, 1.4);
        obruchMain.add(torus2);
```

Comment: Используйте `const group = new THREE.Group();` и добавьте туда свои объекты которые хотите объединить `group.add(torus2)`

Comment: Заодно можно посмотреть в сторону InstancedMesh.